# jQuery animation script runs only first animation function in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation

So I have this Javascript code block (see below), and it works in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. In IE, it runs the first animation `function $(".slide1_background").animate({ yada yada yada` and then nothing. I tried putting an alert after it and that won't fire either.

There is a separate slider script for the background image. It's a Joomla module.

The site is located [here](http://www.bigideaadv.com/a-z/).

Can anyone shed any light on this situation?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    swap();
});

function swap() { //INITIAL LOAD AND SLIDE
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".slide1_background").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack');

        $(".slide1_text").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
            $(".slide2_background").css("left","960px");
            $(".slide2_text").css("left","493px");
            slideInSlide2();
        });
    }, 9000);
};

function slideInSlide2() {
    //BEGINNING OF LOOP
    $(".slide2_background").animate({
        left: '-=468',
        opacity: '1',
        display: 'block'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {      
        $(".slide2_text").animate({
        left: '-=468',
        opacity: '1',
        display: 'block'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
        slideOutSlide2();
    });
}, 200);
}

function slideOutSlide2() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".slide2_background").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

        });

    $(".slide2_text").animate({
        left: '-=1973',
        opacity: '1',
        display: 'block'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
        $(".slide3_background").css("left","960px");
        $(".slide3_text").css("left","960px");
        slideInSlide3();
    });
}, 6800);
};

function slideInSlide3() {
$(".slide3_background").animate({
    left: '-=468',
    opacity: '1',
    display: 'block'
}, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

});

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".slide3_text").animate({
        left: '-=468',
        opacity: '1',
        display: 'block'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
        slideOutSlide3();
    });
}, 200);
}

    function slideOutSlide3() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".slide3_background").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

        });

        $(".slide3_text").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
            $(".slide1_background").css("left","960px");
            $(".slide1_text").css("left","960px");
            slideInSlide1();
        });
    }, 6800);
};

function slideInSlide1() {
    $(".slide1_background").animate({
        left: '-=468',
        opacity: '1',
        display: 'block'
    }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

    });

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".slide1_text").animate({
            left: '-=468',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
            slideOutSlide1();
        });
    }, 200);
}

function slideOutSlide1() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".slide1_background").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {

        });

        $(".slide1_text").animate({
            left: '-=1973',
            opacity: '1',
            display: 'block'
        }, 1000, 'easeOutBack', function() {
            $(".slide2_background").css("left","960px");
            $(".slide2_text").css("left","493px");
            slideInSlide2(); //LOOP AGAIN
        });
    }, 6800);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.setTimeout.live(function() {
```

try that

Comment: I'm assuming it's either a syntax issue or using something other than window.setTimeout like  window.setTimeout.live but not that. window.setTimeout.live halts all the easeOut animation. Even the first one. There must be something else.